# Java Exclusive MIDI usage workaround?

Tags: linux, audio, java, alsa

I'm using a java applet, Jalmus to be specific, that implements MIDI usage.
Whenever Jalmus is running, MIDI Input works (Midi Out doesn't but I don't need that) however, when attempting to connect the same MIDI Input in JACK via ALSA (QJackCtl) to a soft synth, I just can"t.
"ALSA Connection graph change" is shown but no connection line is drawn, nor does the connection work. It seems like Jalmus has taken exclusive use of that MIDI Input.

The problem is mutual: when I start JACK first, I can connect the soft synth in QJackCtl but Jalmus then doesn't get any input.

Is there any workaround for this?